# Java program doesn't show an output

Tags: java

I have the following problem, every time I run this program, it shows an empty screen. I don't know What I am missing.

The problem I am trying to solve is giving two roads (arrays) in which each element represents the time it takes to go through, find the shortest path. You can switch between two roads only one time.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int shortestRoad(int[] road1, int[] road2) {
        return shortestRoadNumbers(road1, road2, 0);
    }

    private static int shortestRoadNumbers(int[] road1, int[] road2, int index) {
        if (index == road1.length || index == road1.length) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (road1[index] >= road2[index] && road1[index + 2] >= road2[index + 2]){
            return (road2[index] + shortestRoadNumbers(road1, road2, index + 1));
        }
        else 
            return (road1[index] + shortestRoadNumbers(road1, road2, index + 1));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] road1 = new int[] { 5, 4, 5, 8, 12, 9, 9, 3 };
        int[] road2 = new int[] { 7, 3, 3, 12, 10, 2, 10, 7 };
        MyClass.shortestRoad(road1, road2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler converts your code to a form that is more readily understood by the java virtual machine (JVM). After compiling (e.g., with `javac`), are you running your program with `java`? I see that your question is in the context of compilation. In that context, without running the program, output would not be expected.

Comment: Could your program still be running? Your first if-statement compares road1.length to index twice. I'm assuming you meant road2.length for one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're calling the `shortestRoad` function, but not retaining nor printing the output.

The following approach outputs the result.

```java
int result = MyClass.shortestRoad(road1, road2);
System.out.println(result);
```